# Não cadastra no Banco JavaWeb PrimeFaces

Tags: java, mysql, primefaces

ProdutoDao:

```
 public class ProdutoDao implements IDao<Produto> {

     @Override
    public List<Produto> listar() {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Produto pro");
            List<Produto> produtos = query.list();
            if (produtos.isEmpty() || produtos == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return produtos;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ArrayList<Produto>();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void inserir(Produto t) {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(t);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{ session.close(); }
    }

    @Override
    public void alterar(Produto t) {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.saveOrUpdate(t);
            session.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{ session.close(); }
    }

    @Override
    public void deletar(Produto t) {
       Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction beginTransaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("delete from produto p where p.id = :id");
            query.setParameter("id", t.getId());
            query.executeUpdate();
            beginTransaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {

            session.close();
        }    
    }

}
```

IDao:

```
public interface IDao<T> {
    public List<T> listar();
    public void inserir(T t);
    public void alterar(T t);
    public void deletar(T t);
}
```

ProdutoBean:

```
public class ProdutoBean {
    private Produto produto;
    private List<Produto> produtos;

    public ProdutoBean() {
        produto = new Produto();
        produtos = new ProdutoDao().listar();
    }

    public void inserir() {
        ProdutoDao produtoDao = new ProdutoDao();
        if (produto.getId() != null && produto.getId() > 0) {
            produtoDao.alterar(produto);
        } else {
            produtoDao.inserir(produto);
        }
        produto = new Produto();
        produtos = produtoDao.listar();
    }

    public void editar(Produto pro) {
        this.produto = pro;
    }
    public void deletar(Produto pro) {
        ProdutoDao produtoDao = new ProdutoDao();
        produtoDao.deletar(pro);
        produto = new Produto();
    }

    public Produto getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
        return produtos;
    }

    public void setProdutos(List<Produto> produtos) {
        this.produtos = produtos;
    }



}
```

Tela de Cadastro:

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>PrimeFaces</title>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <h:form id="frmCadastro">
                    <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="3" cellpadding="5">

                        <p:outputLabel for="nome"  value="Nome: "></p:outputLabel>
                        <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{produtoBean.produto.nome}" />
                        <p:message for="nome"/>

                        <p:outputLabel for="quantidade"  value="Quantidade de Produto: "></p:outputLabel>
                        <p:spinner id="quantidade" min="10" max="20"
                                   value="#{produtoBean.produto.qtd}" />
                        <p:message for="quantidade"/>

                         <p:outputLabel for="data_cad"  value="Data de Cadastro: "></p:outputLabel>
                        <p:calendar id="data_cad" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true"
                                    pages="2" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.dataCad}" />
                        <p:message for="data_cad"/>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <p:commandButton id="submitForm" value="Salvar" update="grid" 
                                     action="#{produtoBean.salvar()}"/>


                    <p:separator ></p:separator>
                    <p:dataTable var="p" value="#{produtoBean.produtos}" rows="3"
                                 paginator="true">
                        <p:column headerText="Nome">
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.nome}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Data de Cadastro">
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.dataCad}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Operações">
                            <p:commandButton value="Editar" action="#{produtoBean.alterar(p)}" update="@form"></p:commandButton>
                            <p:commandButton value="Deletar" 
                                             action="#{produtoBean.deletar(p)}" update="@form"></p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você executou o projeto em modo debug? Se sim, o método inserir de ProdutoDao é invocado? É executado todo try sem erro nenhum?

Se ainda não executou o projeto em debug, execute-o e nos informe se apresenta algum erro no console.